# Passing SQL results from controller to chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, chart.js

**Situation**
I would like to pass the count of X from my SQL database from my controller to my view where a chart picks up this data and renders it.

**What I have done so far**

So far I have the controller code. which gets the count from the table and I am trying to pass this figure back to the chart.

```
public ActionResult currentPopulation()
{            
    var dests = db.personal_info.Count();
   // return Json(dests, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dests), "application/json");
}
```

I also have the chart (code below) from the view

```
<script>

        var barChartData = {
                    url: '/Home/currentPopulation',//Local
                  type: "GET",
                 dataType: "JSON",

            labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
            datasets: [

            {
             //   url: '/Home/currentPopulation',//Local
               //  type: "GET",
               //  dataType: "JSON",

                fillColor: "#26B99A", //rgba(220,220,220,0.5)
                strokeColor: "#26B99A", //rgba(220,220,220,0.8)
                highlightFill: "#36CAAB", //rgba(220,220,220,0.75)
                highlightStroke: "#36CAAB", //rgba(220,220,220,1)
                data: [51, 30, 40], //this is the hard coded values which the chart loads 
                                    //
            },

            ],
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {

  //  new Chart($("#canvas_bar").get(0).getContext("2d")).Bar()

new Chart($("#canvas_bar").get(0).getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, {
tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
responsive: true,
barDatasetSpacing: 6,
barValueSpacing: 5
});

});

</script>
```

**Problem**

The problem I have is that, I cannot replace the [51,30,40] for the A,B,C values 
which is supposed to come from my controller. I am a bit confused as my action "currentPopulation" is not getting called, and i cannot move the link cause according to the code, the data is picked up from barChartData and assign when the new chart is called.

```
new Chart($("#canvas_bar").get(0).getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, {
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your controller to be hit you need to make an ajax request. This ajax call should be done on the action which you want the controller to be called. Button click or so on. Start using console.logs to debug your javascript.

If you want this code to be execute on page open, wrap the ajax call in `document.ready` function.

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/currentPopulation",
        //data: jsonData, if you need to post some data to the controller.
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var aData = response.d;
        console.log(aData);
        //build here your **data** as object wanted by Bar. Colors which you want and so on, options could be empty object {}. I think is possible to call bar without options, you need to read the documentation.

        var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
    }

    function OnErrorCall(response)
    {
        alert('error');
    }
```

Here I show you little example how to do it. You can just google chart.js with mvc there is a lot of examples. Check if the url is correctly written I think you should remove the / in the begging.

**This is just suggestion.**

Also if you had the money and this is serious chart project use highcharts.js ! This is the best library which can work totally offline and gives you really good flexibility.

**Usefull links:**

[ChartJS documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)